# How to avoid dropping ajax calls when an Oauth access-token expires?

Tags: javascript, ajax, oauth, access-token

I have a javascript browser app (SPA) that calls a server protected by OAuth 2, using short-lived access tokens, and longer-lived refresh tokens.
It happens to be my server and my authorization server (my OAuth), but the problem would apply if I were using Google or any other OAuth 2 authorization server with short-lived access tokens (or any token-based service).

Assuming I make my calls to the server through jQuery $.ajax().
When I make a call with an invalid token, the server returns a 401, and I have to request a new access token with my refresh token. I don't need, nor want to bother the user, my app can re-authenticate without them.

The token being short-lived, this could happen every 5 mins or every hour or so. If it happens when I'm making a post, I don't want to lose the information. I need to repeat the post.

Note also that I tend to make a lot of these ajax calls, and have no guarantee which will respond first - they're asynchronous after all.

My question is how do we deal with this? Is there a simple way to replay my posts when I get a 401 - that works nicely for many calls being out at the same time?

Also, is this not common problem with OAUth clients? Why can't I find a lot of documentation and libraries for it?

(I have found some, like this one: https://github.com/esbenp/jquery-oauth, but I would expected this to be more of a mainstream problem with solutions everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the token expiration before every request. If the token is expired begin the refresh process and then make the request after updating the token. Ideally you would know the token expiration time, if not then you could check against a 401 response. 
With OAuth 2 you should know the token expiration time. This could be a simple check run before each request that requires authentication.